# Проблемы с gradle в андроид студио

Tags: android-studio

перейду сразу к вопросу: при загрузке проекта начала возникать ошибка следующего типа, прикладываю скрин:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в проекте: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
Пробовал эти две ссылки в описании, не помогло, в чем может быть проблема и как ее решать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Не пробовали нажимать строчку "Re-download dependencies and sync project"?

Comment: пробовал, то же самое